# How to resolve "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType" error, while working on a flask app with ajax methods?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

Here is my flask app which is using ajax to use html user input data in python script:

**templates/index.html:**

```
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <title>Data Analytics Ireland</title></head>
<body>

<P>Post some values to a json file</P>


<label for="fname">First name:</label> <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
<label for="lname">Last name:</label><input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">

<a href="/test" onclick='myfunction();'>Click Here to see your data</a>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function myfunction() {

        const firstname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
        const lastname = document.getElementById("lname").value;


        const dict_values = {firstname, lastname} //Pass the javascript variables to a dictionary.
        const s = JSON.stringify(dict_values); // Stringify converts a JavaScript object or value to a JSON string
        console.log(s); // Prints the variables to console window, which are in the JSON format
        $.ajax({
            url:"/test",
            type:"POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(s)});
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**main.py**

```
import json

from flask import request

from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():

    output = request.get_json()
    print(output) # This is the output that was stored in the JSON within the browser
    print(type(output))
    result = json.loads(output) #this converts the json output to a python dictionary
    print(result) # Printing the new dictionary
    print(type(result))#this shows the json converted as a python dictionary
    print("********************************") #printing till here
    return render_template('index.html') # this line giving error


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Output:**

```
{"firstname":"noob","lastname":"master"}
<class 'str'>
{'firstname': 'noob', 'lastname': 'master'}
<class 'dict'>
********************************
```

**Issue:** If you look at the output, it printing everything fine in the terminal. But the last code line, where I am returning render_template, its showing error that **"TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not NoneType"** on my webpage instead of returning "index.html" webpage. Also attaching image of debugger showing error:

[image]

This is a complete code so you can try running it at your end also and see if it shows the same error because I am hoping its not browser or version error. I am new to flask and first timer with  html/css.

Thank you.

Comment: I noticed that you are using `JSON.stringify` twice. You just need it once. So doing `data: JSON.stringify(dict_values);` should be enough. I assume this might be the reason data you are receiving is `none`.

Comment: This worked. I did exactly as you said. Now instead of json its directly returning dict so I commented 'json.loads(output)'. But for some reason, my script running twice. 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2022 12:33:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
None
<class 'NoneType'>
********************************
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2022 12:33:21] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 -
{'firstname': 'sanjay', 'lastname': 'bhatt'}
<class 'dict'>
********************************
127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2022 12:33:22] "POST /test HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: As you can see, first its giving none and then the inputs which I entered. I am not able to get how its running twice when I am clicking my anchor tag.

Comment: Open Chrome dev tools, go to the Network tab. Check the `Preserve log` checkbox. Now check if there are 2 requests to your end point or not. If there are 2 then the backend is correct. You would need to figure out why there are 2 outgoing requests.

Comment: found my issue but unable to resolve. For '/test' route, when I am using methods=['GET', 'POST'], its running twice. When I am using only methods=['POST'], its running fine, giving correct print on the terminal but not returing render_template. Instead its showing "The method is not allowed for the requested URL.". And last, when I am using only methods=['GET'], its returning render template but on terminal output dictionaly is None <class 'NoneType'>.

Comment: The last issue is because you are sending a `GET` request which can not have a body attached to it.

Comment: How can I resolve it?

Comment: I am not sure as I have not used `flask` before. Though I noticed you are using `request.get_json()` and then `json.loads` as well, From what I can gather from the docs, `get_json` returns a `dict` so you probably shouldn't use `json.loads`.

Comment: yes that I have edited already if you see my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

you need to define dataType and contentType and you are using two times JSON.stringify

```
function myfunction() {

    var firstname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var lastname = document.getElementById("lname").value;


    var dict_values = {firstname, lastname} //Pass the javascript variables to a dictionary.
    console.log(dict_values); // Prints the variables to console window, which are in the JSON format
    $.ajax({
        url:"/test",
        type:"POST",
        dataType : "json",
        contentType : "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(dict_values)});
}
```

Comment: This worked. I did exactly as you said. Now instead of json its directly returning dict so I commented 'json.loads(output)'. But for some reason, my script running twice. 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2022 12:33:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - None <class 'NoneType'> ******************************** 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2022 12:33:21] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 - {'firstname': 'sanjay', 'lastname': 'bhatt'} <class 'dict'> ******************************** 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2022 12:33:22] "POST /test HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: did you also comment `print(result)` and `print(type(result))` ?

Comment: Yes. I have found my issue but unable to resolve. For '/test' route, when I am using methods=['GET', 'POST'], its running twice. When I am using only methods=['POST'], its running fine, giving correct print on the terminal but not returing render_template. Instead its showing "The method is not allowed for the requested URL.". And last, when I am using only methods=['GET'], its returning render template but on terminal output dictionaly is None <class 'NoneType'>.

Answer (score 1):

**JSON.stringify** converts Javascript Object to string. we can see you are converting `const s` to string twice. Please remove one JSON.stringify and check.

Comment: This worked. I did exactly as you said. Now instead of json its directly returning dict so I commented 'json.loads(output)'. But for some reason, my script running twice.  127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2022 12:33:14] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 - None <class 'NoneType'> ******************************** 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2022 12:33:21] "GET /test HTTP/1.1" 200 - {'firstname': 'sanjay', 'lastname': 'bhatt'} <class 'dict'> ******************************** 127.0.0.1 - - [17/Jan/2022 12:33:22] "POST /test HTTP/1.1" 200 -